# How to retrieve Logged In User’s Credentials from device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a login page in my Ionic App. The current behavior of the app is as below:

1. After downloading the app, User launches it.
2. The app shows Login Options (buttons) page (right now, I only have Microsoft (Azure Active Directory)).
3. Tapping any of the options, the app asks for login credentials (email and password).
4. The app authenticates these credentials against the server/corresponding vendors.
5. Upon successful authentication, the user is taken to Home Page of the app.

Now the important part, for all the subsequent launches, when the user taps on the 'Microsoft' (again, this is the only option I have right now) button it doesn't ask for credentials (emails ID and password). Instead it takes the User to Home Page directly.

So, I am sure the user credentials and/or its corresponding token or something similar is being maintained in the device somewhere.

How do I access this information programmatically?

What I am trying to achieve is: If the user credentials/token already exist on the device then don't even shot the Login Options Page. Take the user to the Home Page directly after the app is launched.

Any ideas/pointers/suggestions on how this can be done.

Thank you!

Comment: What plugin are you using for the active directory login?

Comment: @sebaferreras - I should have been more clearer while mentioning active directory. I will update the original port to mention it. So, I am using azure active directory. Microsoft provides an ADAL library called `cordova-plugin-ms-adal` to interact with AAD, I am using that one.